# 3 snails on a triangle. When will they all approach one another?

Tags: lateral-thinking, physics

There are 3 snails at the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side length L.
Snail 1 crawls towards snail 2, snail 2 towards 3, and 3 towards 1. All snails crawl at the constant speed V.

If they start at time $t=0$, when will they meet?

Answer (score 4):

As snails come to each other, triangle side will shrink. Speed of the shrink will be

> $v+\dfrac{v}{2}=\dfrac{3v}{2}$.
>  Illustration:
>
>  [image: Triangle shrinking speed]

And time for side to become zero will be

> $\dfrac{L}{\left(\frac{3v}{2}\right)}=\dfrac{2L}{3v}$

Comment: But how do you know they are always forming an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @nadapez Symmetry enforces that.